# How to find the smallest value greater than 0 in a or-tools 1-D array (python , or-tools )

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I have a or-tools's 1-D integer array,the value of this array is uncertain and I want to find the smallest value greater than 0, such as [2,0,3,5,0,6,8,9] I want to find the smallest value 2  how can I do it?

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()


work={}

for i in range(8):
    work[i]=model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "work(%i)" % (i))

model.Add(work[0]==2)
model.Add(work[1]==0)
model.Add(work[2]==3)
model.Add(work[3]==5)
model.Add(work[4]==0)
model.Add(work[5]==6)
model.Add(work[6]==8)
model.Add(work[7]==9)


min_value = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "")

#this code only found 0, but did not find the 2 I wanted
model.AddMinEquality(min_value, [work[i] for i in range(8)])

status = solver.Solve(model)
print("status:",status)  

print("min value:",solver.Value(min_value))
```

Comment: do the same thing as you would do if you were not using a computer

Comment: hi, @ jsotola ,sorry my english, I mean i have a or-tools 1-D integer array , The value of this array is uncertain，I want find out smallest value that greater than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just scan the list of integers and remember the minimal non negative integer.

From your description, you do not need a NP-hard solver for a simple linear algorithm.

If you array x is an array of integer variable. Provided M is the max value,
create a second parallel array y of variable with domain [1..M + 1]

for each variable xi, link it to yi with the following code:

```
lit = model.NewBoolVar('')
model.Add(xi > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)
model.Add(xi == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(lit.Not())
model.Add(yi == xi).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)
model.Add(yi == M + 1).OnlyEnforceIf(lit.Not())
```

Then what you want is the min of the y array.

Comment: hi,@Laurent Perron ,sorry my english, I mean i have a or-tools 1-D integer array , The value of this array is uncertain，I want find out smallest value that greater than 0.